# To Dismiss dialog

Tags: android, xamarin, dialog

I wrote this code:

```
            button.Click += (s, e) =>
            {
                string strDialog = "Hello";
                Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
                dialog.Window.RequestFeature(WindowFeatures.NoTitle);
                dialog.SetContentView(Resource.Layout.SDialog);
                TextView text = (TextView)dialog.FindViewById(Resource.Id.dialog_text_view);
                text.Text = strDialog;
(Button)dialog.FindViewById(Resource.Id.dismiss_dialog_button);
                dialogButton.Click += delegate
                {
                    dialog.Dismiss();
                };
                dialog.Show();
            };
```

When I click "button", dialog is opened. When I do not close the dialog and I click "button" again, the dialog is closed. Has been the dialog Dismissed in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    string strDialog = "Hello";
    Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
    // dialog.SetCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
    dialog.Window.RequestFeature(WindowFeatures.NoTitle);
    dialog.SetContentView(Resource.Layout.DialogView);
    dialog.DismissEvent += Dialog_DismissEvent;
    dialog.CancelEvent += Dialog_CancelEvent;
    TextView text = (TextView)dialog.FindViewById(Resource.Id.MyTextView);
    text.Text = strDialog;
    var dialogButton = (Button)dialog.FindViewById(Resource.Id.DismissBtn);
    dialogButton.Click += delegate
    {
        dialog.Dismiss();
    };
    dialog.Show();

}

private void Dialog_CancelEvent(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    //cancel
}

private void Dialog_DismissEvent(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    //dismiss
}
```

I set two breakpoints at the `Dialog_CancelEvent` and `Dialog_DismissEvent`. `Dialog_CancelEvent` was called first and then `Dialog_DismissEvent` was called when touch out side the window's bounds dismissed dialog.If you dismiss dialog by clicking `DismissBtn`,only the `Dialog_DismissEvent` is called.Either way,the dialog was dismissed.

If you don't want the dialog to be dismissed when you click outside of the Dialog, you can use `dialog.SetCanceledOnTouchOutside(false)`.